# Android como otimizar uma grande cadeia de ifs

Tags: java, android, otimização

Gostaria de saber como otimizar uma grande cadeia de ifs de forma que o código fique mais eficiente e mais legível.

Minha aplicação Android usa a versão 2.3.3 (API 10), nesta aplicação tenho uma activity responsável por exibir as informações da conta do usuário, onde o mesmo pode editar essas informações e atualizar. Essa activity contém 8 campos ao lado de campo tem 1 botão "Editar" e um botão "OK" escondido, se o botão "Editar" for clicado então a aplicação esconde o "Editar" e exibe o "OK" no mesmo lugar. Dessa forma tenho ao total 16 botões, 8 "Editar" e 8 "OK". Que deixaram meu método onClick(View v) com 16 ifs.

Como posso melhorar isso e deixar mais eficiente e mais legível? Sei que posso usar o switch que seria quase a mesma coisa.

O código abaixo tem o método com apenas 2 dos 16 botões para simplificar, já que os outros botões seguem a mesma lógica.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btneditar1) {
        camponome.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        camponome.setFocusable(true);
        camponome.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);            
        camponome.requestFocus();
        imm.showSoftInput(camponome, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        btneditar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnok1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnok1) {
        CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateNotNull(camponome, "Campos sem dados são inválidos!");
        if(CampoValido) {
            CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateNotEqual(camponome, bnome);
            if(CampoValido) {
                final String nome = camponome.getText().toString().trim();
                atualizar.execute(usuario, nome, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                txtnomebd.setText(nome);
            }
            camponome.setFocusable(false);
            camponome.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);           
            camponome.requestFocus();
            btnok1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btneditar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }           
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btneditar2) {
        camposobrenome.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        camposobrenome.setFocusable(true);
        camposobrenome.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);           
        camposobrenome.requestFocus();
        imm.showSoftInput(camposobrenome, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        btneditar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnok2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnok2) {
        CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateNotNull(camposobrenome, "Campos sem dados são inválidos!");
        if(CampoValido) {
            CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateNotEqual(camposobrenome, bsobrenome);
            if(CampoValido) {
                final String sobrenome = camposobrenome.getText().toString().trim();
                atualizar.execute(usuario, null, sobrenome, null, null, null, null, null);
                txtsobrenomebd.setText(sobrenome);
            }
            camposobrenome.setFocusable(false);
            camposobrenome.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);          
            camposobrenome.requestFocus();
            btnok2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btneditar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }           
    }           

}
```

Comment: Tente usar [switch...case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) para todos os ifs do código. Agora tem muito conteúdo ai que está repetido em várias funções, otimizar isso seria criar uma nova lógica pra você, e nem conhecemos seu programa.

Comment: @Diego Felipe Como disse na pergunta o switch é quase a mesma coisa não vai otimizar nada.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "otimizar"? O grande problema do código não são nem os ifs, e sim o número de funções repetidas dentro de algumas condições. E como já disse, otimizar isso seria quase o mesmo que recriar sua lógica. Parece que dá pra usar ArrayList de objetos também.

Comment: @Diego Felipe Sim eu tive que repetir as funções, pois cada uma além de afetar um campo diferente, ela afeta um botão diferente. Mas é uma boa ideia fazer um único método onde passo como parâmetro o campo e o botão.

Comment: Tenho uma idéia de como resolver isso, mas não sei se é otimizada, vou postar aqui nos comentários e você da uma olhada

Comment: @Diego Felipe ok.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante: Você está sobrepondo o método onClick da Activity? O que mais costumo ver é algo do tipo `findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... seu código ...} );` , que eu considero mais legível. De qualquer forma, seria um grande avanço separar esses corpos dos ifs em suas devidas funções privadas adequadamente nomeadas. Quanto ao desempenho, a não ser que você tenha notado alguma lentidão nessa parte do código, não se preocupe com isso precipitadamente.

Comment: @Pablo Se eu fosse colocar o Listener em cada botão dessa maneira, iria aumentar o tamanho do código significativamente. Eu não sei se ficaria mais legível, mas pelo fato de aumentar muito o tamanho do código eu prefiro centralizar o Listener de todos os botões em um método.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante Eu prefiro para a depuração, mas esse ponto é mesmo questão de gosto. Mas os outros dois conselhos eu sugiro que considere.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante considere utilizar switch ou utilize if....if else. Do jeito que está toda vez que o usuário clicar em um botão os 16 ifs serão consumidos.

Comment: @Arubu Você esta certo nesse ponto, do jeito que esta ele consome os 16 ifs. Se eu for utilizar mesmo os ifs farei isso.

Comment: @Pablo Ao pensar na sua ideia de colocar o Listener em cada botão com seu método da forma que você disse, pode até ser que aumente o tamanho do código, mas acho que dessa forma ele vai consumir menos recursos de processamento já que ele não vai verificar qual botão foi apertado e sim vai executar diretamente o que está no método do botão. No entanto meu onCreate() vai ficar maior e quando a activity for iniciada ele vai consumir mais recursos nesse momento. Bom é só o que eu acho, não tenho certeza.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante Sim, provavelmente isso acontece. Mas a diferença provavelmente é tão pequena que, para todos os efeitos e propósitos, é a mesma coisa. Sugiro que você pare de se preocupar com desempenho dessa forma a não ser que você realmente meça alguma diferença. Existem ferramentas chamdas _profilers_ que servem para encontrar onde estão os "gargalos" da sua aplicação. Use-os nessas situações e, enquanto não for necessário, preocupe-se mais com a legibilidade que, assim, você ganha mais tempo no médio e longo prazos.

Comment: Verificar esses 16 ifs é praticamente nada para os processadores atuais. Foca no que o @Pablo falou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao refletir sobre os comentários e fazer algumas pesquisas. Para esse caso em específico, a única forma de otimizar os ifs seria colocar um Listener em cada botão no método onCreate() ficando assim:

```
findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... seu código ...} );
```

Porém ao fazer isso eu sobrecarrego método onCreate(), ou seja, ao otimizar uma coisa sobrecarrego outra. Não sei se isso seria melhor, mas com a ajuda dos comentários cheguei a conclusão de que os ifs nesse caso não eram o problema e sim o fato de repetir funções. Eu estava preocupado com ifs e esqueci de usar a orientação a objeto. Então a única otimização feita foi fazer um único método para a ação de todos os botões que usam esse método, passando como parâmetro o que diferencia na ação de cada botão ficou assim:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ControlaBanco bd = new ControlaBanco(getBaseContext());
    Cursor dados = bd.pegaUsuario();
    bnome = dados.getString(2);
    bsobrenome = dados.getString(3);
    busuario= dados.getString(4);
    bpaisregiao = dados.getString(6);
    bdatanasc = dados.getString(7);
    bsexo = dados.getString(8);
    bemail = dados.getString(9);

    boolean CampoValido = false;
    TarefaAtualizar atualizar = new TarefaAtualizar(this);
    final String usuario = busuario;

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btneditar1) {
        AcaoEditarCampo(camponome, btneditar2, btnok2);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnok1) {
        CampoValido = AcaoOkCampo(camponome, bnome, btnok2, btneditar2);
        if(CampoValido) {
            final String nome = camponome.getText().toString().trim();
            atualizar.execute(usuario, nome, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            txtnomebd.setText(nome);
        }
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btneditar2) {
        AcaoEditarCampo(camposobrenome, btneditar3, btnok3);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnok2) {
        CampoValido = AcaoOkCampo(camposobrenome, bsobrenome, btnok3, btneditar3);
        if(CampoValido) {
            final String sobrenome = camposobrenome.getText().toString().trim();
            atualizar.execute(usuario, null, sobrenome, null, null, null, null, null);
            txtsobrenomebd.setText(sobrenome);
        }
    }   

}

private void AcaoEditarCampo(EditText Campo, Button BotaoEditar, Button BotaoOk) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    Campo.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
    Campo.setFocusable(true);
    Campo.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);            
    Campo.requestFocus();
    imm.showSoftInput(Campo, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    BotaoEditar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    BotaoOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private boolean AcaoOkCampo(EditText Campo, String bcampo, Button BotaoOk, Button BotaoEditar) {
    boolean CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateNotNull(Campo, "Campos sem dados são inválidos!");
    if(CampoValido) {
        if(Campo.getInputType() == (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS + 1)) {
            CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateEmail(Campo);
            if(!CampoValido) {
                return CampoValido;
            }
        }           
        if(CampoValido) {
            CampoValido = ValidaCampo.validateNotEqual(Campo, bcampo);
        }
        Campo.setFocusable(false);
        Campo.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);           
        Campo.requestFocus();
        BotaoOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        BotaoEditar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return CampoValido;
}
```

Obrigado a todos que comentaram e ajudaram na minha resposta, vou deixar sem marcar essa resposta como certa por 2 dias para o caso de alguém ter uma resposta melhor.